# search csv stored in html attribute for a given value

Tags: jquery, csv

Say i have a number, `3`.

I'm looking for a way to determine if a given set of jQuery objects contains the number 3 in their attribute. this attribute is often a csv containing ids of countries. could contain one number, could contain multiple.

example tag:

```
<li data-regions="3,52,30">
   <a data-href="/explore/barbados/people/some-person">Some Person</a>
</li>
```

ideally i'd be able to determine if a given list item has the region like so

```
var number = 3;
var els = $('li[data-regions:contains('+number+')]"');
```

Any ideas? if not, do you know how i might be able to extend jQuerys attribute selectors to take a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing answers suggest `*=` which will lead to many false positives. If you can change the data-regions attribute to be space-separated (`"3 52 30"`), you can use the attribute contains word selector (`~=`) like so:

Html:

```
<li data-regions="3 52 30">
    <a data-href="/explore/barbados/people/some-person">Some Person</a>
</li>
```

And the JS:

```
var number = 3;
var els = $('li[data-regions~='+number+')]"');
```

Comment: good thinking. i don't know why i didn't consider that. "Keep It Simple Stupid"

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just break this into pices:

```
var number = 3;
/* First, fetch all li elements that has data-regions attribute */
var els_candidates = $('li[data-regions]'); 
var els = [];

els_candidates.each(function(index) {
  /* Then evaluate if id exists, this way you check for ids, not only chars */
  var regionsArray = $(this).data('regions').split(',');
  if (regionsArray.indexOf(number+'') !== -1) {
    els.push($(this));
  }
});
console.log(els);
```

I am assuming that you need to discriminate the id: 3 (as in your example), and not just the character 3. For example,

```
<li data-regions="1,8,52">
  <a data-href="/explore/barbados/people/some-person">Some Person</a>
</li>
```

Would be evaluated true, if you search for the number 5, instead for the id: 5. That's why I split into pieces the solution to avoid the error.

Comment: I upvoted you for your efforts. I already accepted another solution because it was the correct approach, but i appreciate you taking the time to post this. Thank you!

Comment: You didn't tell you could modify the csv, but the accepted answer has the simplicity we all love, cheers and thanks for the upvt

Comment: I know. I never even considered. If i had, i would never have posted the question lol.

Answer (score 0):

Use `li[data-regions*='3']` it selects all elements with tag name li that have attribute data-regions whose value contains 3

Comment: The downfall of this approach is that it will select "3,52,30" as in the example above, but it will also select "52,30" which is likely not the desired approach.

Comment: @devinallenaz exactly.